# How to set event time slot in custom calendar day view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, calendar

I am developing an app with custom calendar.It includes day view with list of events of that day.I am getting the array of events with overlapped time slots.
Now how can I display the events with proper block adjustment?

I can find the overlapped events group,But not able to set the block adjustment.
Ex:- I have below events

1)From 8:00 To 12:00 event A

2)From 8:00 To 9:00 event B

3)From 9:00 To 10:00 event C

4)From 10:00 To 11:00 event D

5)From 11:00 To 12:00 event E

should be display like below picture.[image]
This is only one type of case,I have many other type of combination.
To draw the Rect I used below method.
*- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 244.0/255.0, 244.0/255.0, 244.0/255.0, 1.0);

for (int i=0; i<arrayRects.count; i++)
{
    if ([[arrayRects objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
    {
        NSMutableArray *confictArray =(NSMutableArray*)[arrayRects objectAtIndex:i];

        for (int j=0; j<confictArray.count; j++)
        {
            NSString *strRect = [confictArray objectAtIndex:j];
            CGRect newRect = CGRectFromString(strRect);
            newRect.size.height -=1.5;
            CGContextFillRect(context, newRect);

            //Draw Line on Left
            {
                if(i==0) {
                    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // green line
                } else if(i==1) {
                    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // red line
                } else {
                    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // blue line
                }

                CGContextBeginPath(context);

                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, newRect.origin.x , newRect.origin.y + 0.5); //start point
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, newRect.origin.x ,newRect.origin.y + newRect.size.height - 0.5); // end path

                CGContextClosePath(context); // close path

                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0); // this is set from now on until you explicitly change it
                CGContextStrokePath(context); //
            }
        }
    }
    else {

        NSString *strRect = [arrayRects objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect newRect = CGRectFromString(strRect);
        newRect.size.height -=1.5;
        CGContextFillRect(context, newRect);

        //Draw Line on Left
        {
            if(i==0) {
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // green line
            } else if(i==1) {
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // red line
            } else {
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // blue line
            }

            CGContextBeginPath(context);

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, newRect.origin.x , newRect.origin.y + 0.5); //start point
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, newRect.origin.x ,newRect.origin.y + newRect.size.height - 0.5); // end path

            CGContextClosePath(context); // close path

            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0); // this is set from now on until you explicitly change it
            CGContextStrokePath(context); //
        }
    }
}*
```

Comment: show your implemented code.

Comment: I got the event time slots from the Database.After that I grouped that events according to below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578730/algorithm-for-finding-overlapping-events-times
So in our case I get 1 group of events,but I can't figure out how to display it.

Comment: i got u what u wanna need but show your code to help u. where u are inserting events in your custom calendar.

Comment: I want to create something like this
http://postimg.org/image/fk5fajms7/

To draw the Rect I used 
                CGContextFillRect(context, newRect);
and the background "time with AM-PM" and lines are drawn in scrollview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71552/discussion-between-vivek-shah-and-dheeraj-singh).